# find a word under mouse pointer in javascript anywhere in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i can find text of an element by using this code.but i want to find a single word any where in my page if mouse hovers on that word for certain time.

```
$(document).bind("mouseover", function (e) {
    var event = e;
    setTimeout(function () { $(event.target).contents().each(function(index, elem) {
        if( elem.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(elem.nodeValue).length ) {
            var text = $.trim(elem.nodeValue);
            text = text.split(" ");
            console.log($.trim(elem.nodeValue));
            //alert($.trim(elem.nodeValue));
            return false;
         }
      });
   }, 5000);
```

});

Comment: A word, unlike its containing element, is not a DOM node, which means it is inaccessible through the DOM.

Comment: is there any other way in java script or jquery to do this?

Comment: I've looked around, but it doesn't look like it. What you'll have to do is wrap your words in inline elements (spans, for example).

Comment: i also have this idea.but its a quite long task to put span or html tags for every word.all the text coming from db or generated dynamically, i have to split it first and put span tags......:(

Comment: How about just splitting and `<span>` wrapping the words in the target element? You do not have to (and should not!) change the entire page. You could then just replace the element in the DOM with the `<span>`d elements which should allow a finer selection of just one word.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely not the best code ever, but it might get you on the right track, going off of andyb's comment.

Something like

```
$(".first").on("hover",function(){

  var words = $(this).text().split(" ");

  var fullText = "";

  for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
    words[i] = "<span>"+words[i]+"</span> "; 
    fullText += words[i];
  }  

  $(this).text("").append(fullText);

  $(this).children("span").on("hover", function(){
    $(".second").text($(this).text());
  });

});
```

Though looking at the [working example](http://jsbin.com/enuqov/2) is your best option.

Comment: +1 nice answer. The only part I would probably do differently is swap the string concatenation for [a faster](http://jsperf.com/array-push-vs-unshift/14) Array `.push()` and then `.join('')` afterwards. In reality it's probably premature optimization :-)

Comment: @andyb Ah yes, good call. I am a designer at heart, so my code is always less than perfect :) Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Sorry, I hope you did not take it the wrong way; it was not a criticism at all. I did not mean to take anything away from this perfectly working solution!

Comment: @andyb No worries, I actually appreciate code review and seeing where I can improve. Every little bit helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).bind("mouseover", function (e) {
      var event = e;
      setTimeout(function () { $(event.target).contents().each(function(index, elem) {
      if( elem.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(elem.nodeValue).length ) {
      var text = $.trim(elem.nodeValue);
      text = text.split(" ");
      var words = (elem.nodeValue).split(" ");

      var fullText = "";

      for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
          words[i] = "<span>"+words[i]+"</span> ";
          fullText += words[i];
      }

      $(event.target).html("").append(fullText);

      $(event.target).children("span").on("hover", function(){
          //$(".second").text($(this).text());
          console.log($(this).text());
       });
          console.log($(event.target).html());

          return false;
       } //alert($(event.target).text()+$(event.target).html());
   });},
```

10000);
});

now my code is this....and working well.but the problem is that now, if an anchor tag or

tag have chailds tag or span tag after some text, it just picks up the text parse it and neglect the child nodes.......:(....i want to pick these child nodes...put span tags for every word and than the outer text